# How can i re-install Yocto on a Intel Edison running with Android Things

Tags: android, intel-edison

I have been using my intel Edison with Android things OS but i would like to return to the Yocto OS system. I tried by using the "intel edison set up  tool "for MAC (Sierra) but the software don't recognize my edison, i also tried by using the terminal ,downloading the Yocto and ./flashall.sh but my Edison is still unrecognizable.

I have already checked my cable connection

Help!

Answer (score 0):

I can't flash my intel [by SD process](https://communities.intel.com/thread/61048) ,but i solved my problem by using the "intel phone flash tool lite" for mac.

I just downloaded Yocto ZIP ,and then flashed it  to my Edison.

I dont know why i can't use the "Edison board configuration tool", it just didn't recognize my edison,....

Here is the link i used to download the intel phone flash tool lite (i did not find it on the oficial page,  for MAC ),

androidmtk.com - Download Intel Phone Flash Tool (all versions)